# Does this question belong on Programmers.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration, software-engineering-se

Earlier today, [a question about implementing a system to spy on cellphone calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715904/how-do-i-make-background-calls-in-android) showed up on Stack Overflow.

I voted to move this question to Programmers, since the answers seemed to revolve around the discussion-y points of the question, instead of an objective, "This is how you do it, with code."

The question was closed as Subjective and Argumentative (which I don't believe it is; but I do believe it should be closed and migrated).

It seems that the author wants code, but in its present form, it's just generating lots of discussion.

Should it be moved to programmers? Or should it stay on Stack Overflow? Or, is there another Stack Exchange site for it?

Comment: I also pointed out that question as a better example for the recent Meta question [Policy regarding questions related to unethical or “shady” practices.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80495/policy-regarding-questions-related-to-unethical-or-shady-practices)  There's an interesting question about technology in there, but man is it going to be hard to rewrite something like that in a way that won't stir up a hornets' nest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the question in its current form would be good for Programmers. It would need  editing to at least include pertinent information like the fact that the OP is talking about phones provided to employees and that it may potentially be legal (if still sketchy).

Considering that the topic is controversial, the question is unclear, the OP has stated in comments that he was looking for implementation details, and the OP has also accepted an answer, I'd say it may be best to let it stay closed on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest editing the question to make it more clear that the OP is looking for code examples.  If it's more clear, perhaps it could be re-opened on Stack Overflow.

However, because of the degree of controversy evoked by this question, no matter what, it is probably going to continue to evoke emotional and argumentative responses and commentary.  Will Stack Overflow benefit from such a question?