# Helping a Phisher?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, ethics

I'm commenting on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551415/capturing-the-browserfield-events-and-its-contents) about parsing data in a BrowserField on Blackberry. I was suspicious about why someone would do this, and tried to persuade the questioner to use other methods of accomplishing their task.

On a recent update, questioner has revealed that they're trying to capture the username and password of someone logging into Gmail. I can think of no reason to do this that doesn't have good intentions for the user, and it looks like they're phishing for passwords.

I'm still interested in the question on an academic level of how to pull data from the BrowserField, but I'm not sure if it's okay to discuss how to steal passwords on StackOverflow.

**Can this be discussed? Should this question be deleted?**

Comment: See also: [Policy regarding questions related to unethical or “shady” practices.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80495/policy-regarding-questions-related-to-unethical-or-shady-practices)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree this user's activity looks a bit strange.

Look at this selection from his question history :

- [Scan for available Wi-Fi networks on BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992052/scan-for-available-wifi-networks-on-blackberry)
- [BlackBerry application autostart and alternate entry point default application icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744938/blackberry-app-autostart-and-alternate-entry-point-default-app-icon)
- [How to launch an application from the browser in BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568503/how-to-launch-app-from-browser-in-blackberry)

however, there is a chance that this is all for legit (although probably badly designed), purposes. He surely deserves a chance to clarify what he's up to.

Comment: I strongly disagree on this. When answering those questions (on the grounds of academic interest) there's a fairly good chance we're helping an unscrupulous script-kiddie hack *our own gmail* account, or send *us* the next batch of spam email or spam forum messages. I'd personally feel rather stupid knowing I helped someone *spam me* or *hack my email*. As a preemptive measure I'm going to downvote such questions every single time I see them.

Comment: @Cosmin what are you talking about? I'm not saying we should answer his questions. Quite the contrary: if it turns out that the user clearly has criminal intentions, the question and/or the whole account needs to be *deleted.* But before that happens, he deserves a chance to defend himself.

Comment: @CosminPrund If you can be hacked by an educated script kiddie, it makes no difference to have helped him or not. You should only care about not helping him hack *other's* mail accounts/whatever. But your security, that should be really hard to break if you care. Just saying :)

Answer (score 39):

He named his files to "facebook-**phish**-scr1.jpg"

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/media/gallerypage/user-id/92310/image-id/1214iCF35FC594B3D7C7D

So, he knows what he is doing :-)

Answer (score 11):

I closed the question, and another moderator deleted it.

It wasn't a difficult decision.

Comment: Fair enough. As said above, some of his other questions may deserve scrutiny as well - but not being an Android expert, I can't judge the degree of their shadiness

Comment: one more got deleted too - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2809230/

Comment: Speaking as an Android person, his 2 Android questions sound harmless to me.

Comment: @John sorry, I meant to say Blackberry. But thanks, I'll take the Android one from my list.