# "Help me spam people" question?

Tags: discussion, support, spam, off-topic

I noticed [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176407/chandni-batra) ask a [really off-topic qustion](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/60982/11762) (actually a question *about* how to spam) on English.Stackexchange. I then noticed the user's account is active across 20 StackExchange sites with 1 rep each, and has posted the same question on [at least one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/27242) other site.

I voted to close the EL&U question as off-topic, but can't do anything about the webmasters one. This is a minimal amount of activity, but it seems like something we'd want to discourage.

**Side note:** The only other question asked by the user was closed as off-topic on webmasters and migrated to SuperUser, where it was closed as "not a real question".

Comment: I've flagged the Webmasters question.

Comment: Related: [Policy regarding questions related to unethical or “shady” practices](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80495/policy-regarding-questions-related-to-unethical-or-shady-practices)

Comment: @Bobby: Actually, the question you linked has no relevance to this issue. The user is indiscriminately asking his question about how to spam on several SE sites, probably much in the same way he spams. He figures if he can throw enough spaghetti against the wall, some of it will stick. What a terrible way to run a life.

Comment: *"I want to send emails to bulk of emails." — I want you to die in a fire. – jwodder 36 mins ago*. Apparently EL&U does not look favorably on spam.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9675231/102937) for the (apparently) *right* way to ask people on SE to help you spam.

Comment: _"He figures if he can throw enough spaghetti against the wall, some of it will stick. What a terrible way to run a life." – @RobertHarvey_ Excuse me? You, sir, just don't understand __art__.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The user's profiles and questions have been destroyed on both sites.

Thanks for bringing it to our attention - this is straight-up abuse.

Comment: Waiting to see if he comes back; if necessary, we can suspend all of those profiles en masse.