# Should the [jailbreak] tag from Stack Overflow be removed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ethics

As good programmers, should we support illegal jailbreaking of devices (which includes Android phones as well), and support the [jailbreak](/questions/tagged/jailbreak) tag?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80495/

Comment: Why should jailbreaking **your** phone be illegal? It's a pure nonsence. If you have bought something, you can do with it what you want, even fry it and eat with ketchup.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Jailbreaking an iPhone or Android is not illegal.  The former is against the terms of agreement with Apple, but neither are a violation of any law passed by congress and signed by the president.

Keep it.

Comment: +1, Ohhh okay, never knew that...Thanks

Comment: And if it _was_ a law signed off by the president of the USA, well, I for one live in Australia... (And anyway I don't see how Apple can expect me to follow the terms of their agreement when their standard warranty policy appears to be in violation of Australian consumer law.)

Comment: @nnnn - yeah, I was wondering if anyone was going to bring that up (for Australia or anywhere).  Looking at other meta questions, it looks like there's a fairly clear policy to allow questions about jailbroken devices on SU (and elsewhere, I would assume), so I'm pretty happy about that.

Comment: Yeah. The gist of our stance is that we're not really responsible for proactively enforcing third-party licensing or contract agreements. And for non-US folks, there's this line of the [ToS](http://stackexchange.com/legal): `If You access the Network from outside the United States, You do so at Your own risk and You are responsible for compliance with the laws of Your jurisdiction.`

Comment: Fix your code, right now it suggest that jailbreaking an Android is against the Terms of Agreement of Apple

Comment: Sadly, it wouldn't particularly surprise me if that were true... @ajax

Comment: Fair enough, @ajax

Comment: @annalear good to know, but I dont understand that why my question got down voted? It is not likable question but it is a fair question.

Comment: @Brogrammer People were [disagreeing that the tag should be removed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: ...and besides, you don't "jailbreak" an Android. You root it.