# Why did this question get downvoted and closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

It seems very "programming-related"!  What's the deal?!

[Use an iPad 1 for development and debugging in the latest Xcode (4.5), how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399455/use-an-ipad-1-for-development-and-debugging-in-the-latest-xcode-4-5-how)

Comment: It seems that it all boils down to my having used the "J" word, which pushed everyone's buttons

Answer (score 6):

At first glance, the question appears to be about jailbreaking an iPad, which would make it a non-constructive, off-topic question for Stack Overflow.

As a question, it's poorly worded, and had me on the wrong foot at first. I've edited that question to clarify the intent, downplay the jailbreaking aspect, and I have voted to reopen it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just showing my Apple ignorance, but the question looks to me like it's about whether the jailbreaking procedure would allow programming to be done. Doesn't that make it different than the boat question?

Comment: @PopularDemand: Hrm, on second reading, I think you are right. The question isn't the best quality, and could do with some editing to clarify the intent.

Comment: Yeah, it's poorly written for sure. I almost edited it, but decided to leave that for someone else (because, again, Apple ignorance).

Comment: Definitely!  I don't care about jailbreaking... I just want to do iPad development with the equipment I already have instead of having to spend money.  I just brought up jailbreaking to show that I had done some research on my own on the questions and saw mentions online that jailbreaking would allow you to upgrade to iOS 6 (but it was not specifically development-related) so I was just putting that out there as a possible direction

Comment: -1 for the first paragraph. Installing software on your hardware is not non-constructive or off-topic in itself. I did a quick search here on Meta and didn't find any support for the "obviousness"; on the contrary, I found these: [Policy regarding questions related to unethical or "shady" practices](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80495) [Should the jailbreak tag from stackoverflow removed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141724) [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465)

Comment: @EmilVikström: I consider jailbreaking iPads off-topic for SO, on-topic for Think Different or Super User; just because a programmer is doing the jailbreaking does not make it a programming topic.

Comment: @JoelFan - Reading your original question, I don't know if it was the jailbreaking mention that set people off, but the fact that your question was worded in a way that focused on how to upgrade an iPad 1 to iOS 6. OS upgrades are off topic for the site, but Martijn's edit broadened the scope to ask about other ways of debugging on your older iPad using the latest Xcode. The latter is clearly a programming-related question.